Where two M ... Z sequences meet, the background color shows through
I have a very straightforward svg path here, but for some reason, certain parts have the background color when they should be black.  It's a short, well-defined input, and a short, well-defined output.  Does anyone know why that should be the output?
I have put a colored dot at each vertex, for clarity.
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="214" height="317" viewBox="0 0 214 317" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M 199 317 L 107 32.5 L 14.5 317 L 0 317 L 105 0 L 109 0 L 214 317 L 199 317 Z 
                 M 166 199 L 44.5 199 L 41.5 211 L 170.5 211 Z" />
        <!-- The 2nd M...Z is the horizontal piece. -->
        <circle cx="166" cy="199" r="2" fill="red" stroke="none" />
        <circle cx="44.5" cy="199" r="2" fill="green" stroke="none" />
        <circle cx="41.5" cy="211" r="2" fill="blue" stroke="none" />
        <circle cx="170.5" cy="211" r="2" fill="yellow" stroke="none" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>



It happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

As I experiment further, I notice that if I make the horizontal piece a separate path statement, the problem disappears.   I still have no idea why.

Try setting the fill-rule attribute of your path element to "nonzero".

By using two path elements you stack them on top of each other. This will always work. In your original path SVG interprets the second part of your path as a subtraction from the first one. Reversing the points will change that (see my answer below).

As already mentioned it's about the drawing directions. It doesn't matter which shape is clockwise or counterclockwise - if they are overlapping but with alternating directions you'll see this effect as described here "auto colour fill when Generate Font from svg figma icon using icomoon". Just for fun: you can paste your code into this codepen example and click on the path fills.

Change the order of your points in the second part of your d attribute in your <path> element:


<svg width="214" height="317" viewBox="0 0 214 317" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 199 317 L 107 32.5 L 14.5 317 L 0 317 L 105 0 L 109 0 L 214 317 L 199 317 Z 
             M 166 199 L 170.5 211 L 41.5 211 L 44.5 199 Z" />
    <!-- The 2nd M...Z is the horizontal piece. -->
    <circle cx="166" cy="199" r="2" fill="red" stroke="none" />
    <circle cx="44.5" cy="199" r="2" fill="green" stroke="none" />
    <circle cx="41.5" cy="211" r="2" fill="blue" stroke="none" />
    <circle cx="170.5" cy="211" r="2" fill="yellow" stroke="none" />
</svg>



With this changed order of points you can observe the effect of the fill-rule attribute. The default value here is "nonzero", but if you change that to "evenodd" you will be getting your original appearance again:


<svg width="214" height="317" viewBox="0 0 214 317" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 199 317 L 107 32.5 L 14.5 317 L 0 317 L 105 0 L 109 0 L 214 317 L 199 317 Z 
             M 166 199 L 170.5 211 L 41.5 211 L 44.5 199 Z" />
    <!-- The 2nd M...Z is the horizontal piece. -->
    <circle cx="166" cy="199" r="2" fill="red" stroke="none" />
    <circle cx="44.5" cy="199" r="2" fill="green" stroke="none" />
    <circle cx="41.5" cy="211" r="2" fill="blue" stroke="none" />
    <circle cx="170.5" cy="211" r="2" fill="yellow" stroke="none" />
</svg>




That is awesome!   Thank you, Carsten.   The key seems to be:   "In your original path SVG interprets the second part of your path as a subtraction from the first one."   That is a complete surprise to me.   Can you point me to a writeup that explains this?

Indeed, it is not so easy to find a concise description of the SVG path filling behaviour online. Maybe the following one helps? https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch06-fill-rule.html

I'll look at that.   Thank you.   What I just watched was this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpwrNSQtof8   It seemed to help.
